# OAuth middleware in Laravel

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, gluu

I managed to successfully complete the OAuth flow and gain access token for the user. The OAuth is on a separate server & identity provider (OpenID Connect).

Now, I need to add middleware to check that the user is authenticated throughout his session in the application.

Any idea/directions on how I can manage this? Quite lost.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Pathfix does exactly what you are looking for. It is a Serverless OAuth Middleware, If you want to try it out. Might save you a whole lot of time setting up and deploying a middleware.

Disclaimer: I am part of the Pathfix Team :)